# Package error in 12.04 ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, package-management

When using sudo apt-get install libxerces27 libxerces27-dev libopenal0a libglut / 
libglut3-dev libfontcongfig1

It says for every package

```
E: Unable to locate package.
```

I am using precise distribution of linux 12.04

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Do these packages really exist? If these commands return no luck then your packages don't exist in Ubuntu's repositories or your PPAs. Try

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and try again. If that doesn't work then try

```
sudo apt-get install --fix-missing
```

and try again. If that does not work, then this means that your packages are not available in Ubuntu's repos or your PPAs.